# 802.11ac and 802.11n at 5GHz on Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT

Tags: usb, wifi, wireless, windows-iot

Is it possible on a Raspberry Pi 2 (or 3) with Windows 10 IoT Core to have Wi-Fi 802.11ac and 802.11n at 5GHz?

I know the list of compatible hardware: [Hardware Compatibility List - WiFi Dongles](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm#WiFi-Dongles)

None of the Wi-Fi dongles in the list supports 802.11ac or 802.11n at 5 GHz. However, I know that you can make work other Wi-Fi dongles if you get the driver (compiled for ARM) and you install it with `devcon.exe` (I have an Edimax EW-7811UN working on one of my Raspberries with Windows IoT Core after downloading the ARM drivers from the Edimax web page).

Also, I suppose that if you have the source code, you can compile it in the architecture of your choice.

In conclusion, there is some way to obtain the drivers for ARM (or compile it) of a Wi-Fi dongle with 802.11ac or 802.11n at 5 GHz?